# Understand the code for generation of all De Bruijn sequences

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I have some questions regarding [generation of all De Bruijn sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1377263/511447)

What is the purpose of the condition : `2*arrange.count(0) == 2**N` and one other condition: `if not new_seen[seen_i]` ?

How do these conditions count equal zeros and ones and the other is a basic depth-first-search condition to recurse ?

```
# De Bruijn sequences return...
# Generate strings using DFS, ignoring strings with "seen" subsequences

def S(arrange, seen, N):
    # len(arrange) can be removed if 00000 is marked as seen
    if len(arrange) == 2**N and 2*arrange.count(0) == 2**N:
        print(''.join(map(str, arrange)))

    for c in (0, 1):
        new_seen = seen[:]
        new_arrange = arrange + [c]

        word = ''.join(map(str, new_arrange[-N:]))
        seen_i = int(word, 2)

        if not new_seen[seen_i]:
            new_seen[seen_i] = 1
            S(new_arrange, new_seen, N)


S([0]*5, [0]*2**5, 5)  # Beginning must be 00000
```

Comment: What specifically do you not understand? Counting equal zeros and ones is just a shortcut to ensure all 32 length 5 binary substrings are included.

Comment: First of all, do you understand DFS at a high level and how the string is being constructed here?

Comment: @qwr I understand the concept of depth-first-search, but I do not understand how your code constructs the substring/subsequence

Comment: @qwr how is `2*arrange.count(0) == 2**N` equivalent to counting equal zeros and ones ?

Comment: @qwr I had understood the code snippet for counting equal zeros and ones

Comment: @qwr I do not quite understand the purpose of `if not new_seen[seen_i]`